# Lookup in mongodb not working when getting objects from array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate, pipeline, lookup

[Wishlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iafbI.png)
[product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyGrV.png)

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGS5e.png)

[Getting Wishlist Blanked . please help me why wishlist array shows no data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs4F1.png)

Answer (score 0):

`productId` in the `wishList` is a `String`, while the `_id` field in `product` is an `ObjectId`.

You can change the type of the `productId` in the `wishList` or you can use `$lookup` with `let` and `pipeline` to project the `_id` in `product` as a String value before comparing it to `wishList.productId`, like this:

```
{
    "$lookup":
    {
        "from": "products",
        "let":
        {
            "productId": "$wishList.productId"
        },
        "pipeline":
        [
            {
                "$addFields":
                {
                    "idAsString":
                    {
                        "$toString": "$_id"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$match":
                {
                    "$expr":
                    {
                        "$eq":
                        [
                            "$idAsString",
                            "$$productId"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the query, since you didn't provide an easy way to reproduce the error, as mentioned by toyota Supra in the comment to your question, but it should be something along these lines.

Comment: Thanks to clerify my doubt . Its working !

Comment: I'm glad it works. Would you care to accept the answer if it helped you solve the issue?